# How to end the workers of node.js cluster

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

How to kill the workers which are created by cluster when the cluster process killed

Comment: They supposed to get killed too... When the master gets killed...

Comment: But System process wont kill worker process... do u have any solution for this

Comment: I dnt knw Y -1 vote... is this not a prob